# Does Mongodb expireAfterSeconds has callback? And how to catch it with nodejs?

Tags: mongodb, callback, ttl

This is the sample of my code:

```
var changesDB = new mongoose.Schema({
    eventId: String,
    date: Date
})

changesDB.index({ title: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds : 60*60*24*30 });
```

It works fine, but I need to delete all the files connected to this collection, so I have to catch this event with nodejs.
How can I make it?

Answer (score 3):

As of MongoDB 3.0, there's no callback mechanism of any sort in MongoDB; in particular, there is no such mechanism for TTL indexes. The TTL enforcement is just a background thread that queries every minute for documents that have expired, then deletes them. If you have related data that you need to expire, I'd suggest just mimicking the TTL index's operation in your application, where you can perform whatever extra logic is necessary to clean up related data.

Alternatively, you could make all related documents expire at the same time, so they will all be deleted at approximately the same time (within the same TTL pass).